# summation of power of fibonacci number?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

How to find the sum of this series

```
fib(0)^K + fib(C)^K + fib(2*C)^K + fib(3*C)^K + ... + fib(N*C)^K
```

where constraint are `0 < N < 10^15` , `0 < C < 11` and `0 < k < 11`?

Here `fib(i)` is the i-th fibonacci number, where `fib(0)=0` , `fib(1)=1` and `fib(n) = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`. We have to calculate the summation modulo 1000000007 (10^9+7).

Comment: This question might be besser suited for https://math.stackexchange.com as the problem probably requires a deeper understanding of the Fibonacci series, sums of powers, etc. instead of an algorithm.

Comment: [Something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442459/) might get you in the right direction, although this is just for `K=2` and `C=1`...

Comment: How is `fib(i)` defined? Is it the i-th Fibanocci number? Is it the closest Fibanocci number smaller than i? If it is the former, I doubt the constraint for `N` makes sense.

Comment: This sounds like something you might find on HackerRank or similar. Can you share a link to the original problem?

Comment: yeah I found this question on codeforces.                https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=26ec4708f0&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-a:r1776330583322151308&th=169913f72298ea9e&view=att&disp=inline&realattid=f_jteghpzt0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Plesae show us what you've tried. [Edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in manipulating recurrence relations, basically. To understand this answer, you should be comfortable switching between matrix and system form.

First we get a recurrence for `fib(i)^K`. This actually involves a system of recurrences for `fib(i)^K, fib(i)^(K-1) fib(i-1), fib(i)^(K-2) fib(i-1)^2, ..., fib(i-1)^K`. I'll demonstrate for `K = 3`.

```
fib(i)^3 = (fib(i-1) + fib(i-2))^3
         = fib(i-1)^3 + 3 fib(i-1)^2 fib(i-2) + 3 fib(i-1) fib(i-2)^2 + fib(i-2)^3
fib(i)^2 fib(i-1) = (fib(i-1) + fib(i-2))^2 fib(i-1)
                  = fib(i-1)^3 + 2 fib(i-1)^2 fib(i-2) + fib(i-1) fib(i-2)^2
fib(i) fib(i-1)^2 = (fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)) fib(i-1)^2
                  = fib(i-1)^3 + fib(i-1)^2 fib(i-2)
fib(i-1)^3 = fib(i-1)^3
```

These can be combined into a single matrix.

```
[fib(i)^3    fib(i)^2 fib(i-1)    fib(i) fib(i-1)^2    fib(i-1)^3] =
                                                                           i
= [fib(0)^3    fib(0)^2 fib(-1)    fib(0) fib(-1)^2    fib(-1)^3] [1 0 0 0]
                                                                  [3 1 0 0]
                                                                  [3 2 1 0]
                                                                  [1 1 1 1]
                     i
= [0 0 0 1] [1 0 0 0]
            [3 1 0 0]
            [3 2 1 0]
            [1 1 1 1]
```

You may recognize Pascal's triangle over there.

Now, given a system of recurrences for a function `f(i)`, we can compute recurrences for `f(c i)` by raising the matrix to the power `c`.

The final step is to go from a recurrence for `f(i)` to a recurrence for `F(i) = f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(i-1)`. It's simple to add an equation

```
F(i) = F(i-1) + f(i-1)
```

to the system.

Having computed the matrix, which by my estimate will have at most `12^2 = 144` elements, we can compute the appropriate power using fast matrix exponentiation mod `10^9 + 7`. Mind the lurking off-by-one error – that's `F(n+1)` that you want.